# Why does the simplified function $f_1(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$ has a different domain to $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The function
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}} \text{ has } \mathcal{D}(f)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\neq 2 \wedge x\geq -2\}.$$

We can simplify $f(x)$:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}}  = \sqrt{\frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2}} = \sqrt{x+2} = f_1(x)$$

but $$f(x)=\sqrt{x+2} \text{ has } \mathcal{D}(f)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\geq -2\}.$$
Hence $$\mathcal{D(f)}\neq \mathcal{D(f_1)}$$
although $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}}=\sqrt{x+2}=f_1(x)$$

What is wrong here?

Comment: the x-2 in the denominator added a new domain restriction

Comment: Yeah, but why could this happen? I simplified correctly, didn't I?

Comment: Yes, you simplified correctly, but you removed the undefined point at $x = 2$ in the original function. That means it’s not the “same” function.

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot.

Comment: that discontinuity, at x=2, is known as a removable discontinuity. You CAN define the point at x=2 (piecewise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren’t the same function. Through your simplification, you essentially allow $x = 2$ to be part of the domain. The initial function has a “gap” at $x = 2$ where it is undefined.

Comment: Clear statement, thanks. I understood what I did wrong.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f_1$ is defined for each $x\geq -2$ yet $f$ is defined for all $x\geq -2$ and $x\neq 2$ (because in denominator you can't have $x=2$), so they can't be the same function.

Comment: I simplified correctly, shouldn't they be the same functions nevertheless?

Comment: No, because you can simplifed it iff $x\ne 2$. If $x=2$ you can not do simplification.

Comment: If they are the same then tell us what is $f(2)$. Clearly $f_1(2)=2$, what about $f(2)$?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that.